# Find $a,b,c$ such that a complex function of the complex variable is entire. And express it as a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f = u +iv$, where $u(z) = x^3+axy^2$ and $v(z) = bx^2y+cy^3+1$
> Determine the values of real numbers $a, b, c$ that make $f$ an entire function. Then express $f$ as a polynomial funciton of $z$. (From a book by Bruce Palka: *an Introduction To complex functions Theory*, ex. 6.24).

By using Cauchy–Riemann equations, I have found that the function is entire when $a = -3$, $b = 3$ and $c = -1$.
From that I can write $$f(z) = x^3-3xy^2+i(3x^2y-y^3+1)$$
But I am having problems writing this as a polynomial function of $z$. Since $z^3$ = $f -i$ And I can't figure out how to get this extra $i$ written as a polynomial. Maybe I have understood this problem wrongly, or my approuch is way off. Please help.

Comment: I meant function is entire in the title

Comment: $f(z)=z^3+i$ is a polynomial with complex coefficients $(i,0,0,1)$coefficients do not need to be real.

Comment: What @zwim means is that you could have recognized $(x+iy)^3+i=z^3+i$ which indeed is entire.

Answer (score 1):

Here $u(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$ so that
$u_x(z,0)=3z^2$ and $u_y(z,0)=0$.

A glimpse of **Milne-Thomson's method** to construct analytic $f=u+iv$ where $v$ is unique upto arbitrary constant of integration, which is $i$ in your case.
$f(z)=\int [(u_x(z,0)-iu_y(z,0)]dz=\int 3z^2dz=z^3+i$